# Data Binding Buttons windows phone

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Alrite so I'm using visual studio.  I have an array of type string inside of my c# code, and i want to access that array, and have the string from the array shown on a button that i already created. the button itself is already placed but i want to know how to connect the data from my array to the xaml code. any help is appreciated, ty.

Answer (score 0):

Use databinding along these lines `<Button x:Name="b1" Content={Binding Source=YourArray ...}` I am not sure if you want to display an element from the array?